# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are: id

Tags: python, django

I have below classes definition:

```
class A(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=now, null=True, blank=True)
    t = GenericRelation(T, object_id_field='object_id', content_type_field='content_type', related_query_name='a')


class B(A):
    state_path = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, verbose_name="State Path")
    f = GenericRelation(F, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_id', related_query_name='b')

class C(B):
    choice = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Enabled")
    

class T(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created Time")
    # GenericForeignKey fields
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    a = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')



class E(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Username")
    key = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Key")


class F(E):
      content_type = models.OneToOneField(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      b = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


c = C.objects.get(pk=c_id)
c.delete()
```

It returned error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are: id
```

I don't quite get it why... as C doesn't have content_type, and T has on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING for its content_type. Please help correct.

Thanks.

Comment: This probably also has the same effect when deleting (through) the `B` model instead?

Comment: Thanks. But I have a C class instantiated, and there is an additional field:
choice = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Enabled")
I just don't understand why c.delete() will cause this error.